# C# GRPC Reconnect on StatusCode.AlreadyExists

Tags: c#, grpc

I have bi-directional streaming set up between my client (UWP, C#) and a server I don't have control over (written in NodeJS). 
The app is supposed to be running for a long time (days) so it's important that it can recover any loss of connection automatically.

One scenario that is easy to test is the temporary loss of internet connection. While I immediately get an exception in the client that the stream was closed, the server does not seem notice for quite some time.
So when I try restart my `await responseStream.MoveNext()` loop I always get an exception with the `StatusCode.AlreadyExists`.

Same thing happens when I try to force-close the connection with both `CompleteAsync()` and canceling the Token like this:

```cs
await _connectionToServer.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();
cts.Cancel();
```

Is there any way to recover the that existing connection on the client side?

Comment: To be able to detect loss of connection, you may want to use keepalives (see https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/keepalive.md). Otherwise, gRPC doesn't attempt to detect connection loss unless you attempt to send some data.  Also, once connection is lost, the in-flight RPCs will fail (as soon as the connection failure is detected).  When you start a new RPC, the channel will automatically try to reconnect by creating a new connection.  There's no way to "recover" an existing connection - all RPCs associated with the old connection will just fail.

Comment: Also, it looks like the "StatusCode.AlreadyExists" is generated by your own application logic, so this is perhaps something to revisit (looks like you're artificially limiting the number of active RPCs between the client and the server to 1 and it's not working out).